# How to map MongoDB emebded key/value structure to Symfony Form field?

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Let assume the MongoDB record like the one below. Is there a way how to map fields 'meta.fce_id' and 'meta.fce_name' to Symfony2 Form type so I can edit them in browser and Symfony would be able to store it back to MongoDB properly? (we use Doctrine ODM for MongoDB)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("545a72db698ef0bfa5a8fd04"),
    "title" : "David",
    "meta" : {
            "fce_id" : "ADF7584S",
            "fce_name" : "CEO"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This common need is solved by creating form types for the embedded object(s). In your case, you would create a MetaType with its own `id` and `name` fields, and then include that as a `meta` field in the top-most form. The Symfony book entry on [Embedding a Single Object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html#embedding-a-single-object) should walk you through each step of the process. Also useful

If you end up needing to extend this to work with has-many relationships, the cookbook entry on [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) will be helpful. Both articles refer to Doctrine ORM, but they are generic enough that the same concepts should apply to ODM as well.